# In function which flattens data from Kinesis stream, get error pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Reference 'Equipment.units' is ambiguous

Tags: python, pyspark

When I execute function in Python that flattens data from Kinesis stream in a AWS Glue job, I get error-
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Reference 'Equipment.units' is ambiguous, could be: Equipment, Equipment.

also for -

pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Reference 'Equipment.units' is ambiguous, could be: Equipment, Equipment.sweetspot

In schema equiment looks like -

- Equipment: struct
  |    |-- units: null
  |    |-- value: string

-- equipment: struct
|    |-- sweetspot: array
|    |    |-- element: choice
|    |    |    |-- double
|    |    |    |-- int
|    |-- length: double
|    |-- weight: double
|    |-- sensorAttachment: int
|    |-- id: string
|    |-- type: string
|    |-- axeBatRotation: int

Part of function code -
if isinstance(typ, ArrayType):
# If it is a struct array: alphabetize the inner columns
typ = typ.elementType
if isinstance(typ, StructType):
new_list = sorted(typ.names)
expr_list = ', '.join([f'x.{x} as {x.lower()}' for x in new_list])
expr = f"transform({name}, x -> struct({expr_list}))"
fields.append(f.expr(expr).alias(alias.lower()))
else:
fields.append(f.col(name).alias(alias.lower()))
elif isinstance(typ, StructType):
fields += flatten(typ, name_pre=name, alias_pre=alias)
else:
fields.append(f.col(name).alias(alias.lower()))

Tried to print the field names and alias to find what is value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.